# play framework 2.3 change template language without extra request

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.3

The normal way to change the Language is to make redirect responce with

```
.withLang(Lang(newLangCode))
```

but how is better to change current language without extra redirect, I have the following construction. I try to use the language from user record or from request cookies or headers if user has no language.

```
def index(userId:Int) = Action {
val userLang = getUser(userId).getLang.getOrElse(implicitly[Lang])
Ok(views.html.index(...)).withLang(userLang)
}
```

But this approach does not work ofcourse: views.html.index(...) is called with old implicit lang and "withLang" only sets cookie for new request.

I know only one solution: call template function with explicit lang param.

```
def index(userId:Int) = Action {
   implicit request => 
   val userLang = getUser(userId).getLang.getOrElse(implicitly[Lang])
   Ok(views.html.index(...)(request,userLang)).withLang(userLang)
}
```

But may be exists more canonical way to make language switching ?

Comment: I don't know if Play itself has a cleaner way, but manually providing a value to override an inappropriate implicit in scope feels like the canonical way of swapping out implicits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your `userLang` value as implicit. This way your `userLang` value will be automatically picked up for your template argument `@(...)(implicit lang: Lang)`.

```
def index(userId:Int) = Action { request => 
    implicit val userLang = getUser(userId).getLang.getOrElse(implicitly[Lang])
    Ok(views.html.index(...)).withLang(userLang)
}
```

You also need to remove the implicit modifier from the request argument, because in the `Controller` trait there is an [implicit conversion](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Controller.scala#L64) from implicit request to lang, and the compiler will complain for ambiguous implicit parameters.